# Equilateral triangle within a circumscribed circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, triangles

In the attached picture there is an equilateral triangle within a circumscribed circle. MW is a radius of the circle.

[image]

I wish to prove that MT = TW, i.e., that the triangle's edge cuts the radius into equal parts.

I thought perhaps to draw lines AM and AW and to try and prove that I get two identical triangles, but failed to do so. Is it possible to prove this without trigonometry, using Euclidean geometry only ?

I need this because this is the basis for the second way to solve the Bertrand paradox in probability. While I'm OK in probability, I couldn't prove this crucial geometric aspect of the problem. Any help will be most appreciated here.

Comment: *"MW is a radius of the circle"* <<< it's not just any radius - or if it is, then what you are trying to prove is false in general. MT = TW is true if and only if T is the middle of AB.

Answer (score 2):

The [centroid of every triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_triangle) lies on a median at $2/3$ of the way from the vertex to the opposite side. Hence $CM=2MT$ and you are done.

Comment: both radius and then I'm done...I see. I didn't figure out that it's the median, I thought it was the bisection (all bisections meet at the center of the triangle).

Comment: In an equilateral triangle, medians are the same as perpendicular bisectors.

Answer (score 1):

In right angled triangle $MBT$, $MB$ is a bisector.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\angle BMW = 60°$, so $\dfrac{TM}{BM} = \cos60° = \dfrac12$, hence $MT = TW = \dfrac12 BM$

Comment: Why is the angle being 60 degrees ?

Comment: By symmetry, $\angle AMB = 360°/3 = 120°$, and $\angle BMW = \angle AMW = 120°/2 = 60°$

Answer (score 0):

Join point $M$ to point $C$. By inscribed angle in same arc we have $\angle BCW= \angle BAW= 30°$
Similarly we have $\angle AWC= \angle ABC=60°$.
In triangle $MAT$ we already know that $\angle MAT=30°$ and $\angle AMT=60°$. Hence by congruence in $ΔMAT$ and $ΔWAT$ we have $WT=MT$